# Getting error of to many arguments were given - django project

Tags: python, django

I have a django project with a django app called users. in the projects url settings I have it connected to the users app url python file. I want to connect them and have the urls base off of the url patterns in the users urls file.. WHile doing so, I am getting an error that there were to many arguments that were being passed and I have no idea what it means or any reference as to how I can fix this error.

This is the main error that I am getting

I am getting the error when i run the following command `python manage.py runserver`

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x108629378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/MySplit/mysplit/mysplit/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('users.urls')),
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/MySplit/mysplit/users/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/MySplit/mysplit/users/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from general.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm, ProfileForm, VerifyPersonalForm
  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/MySplit/mysplit/general/forms.py", line 60, in <module>
    class VerifyPersonalForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 256, in __new__
    apply_limit_choices_to=False,
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 172, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localflavor/us/models.py", line 81, in formfield
    return super(USZipCodeField, self).formfield(**defaults)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1097, in formfield
    return super().formfield(**defaults)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 874, in formfield
    return form_class(**defaults)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localflavor/us/forms.py", line 42, in __init__
    max_length, min_length, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/localflavor/compat.py", line 16, in __init__
    super(EmptyValueCompatMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Here is the main url file that has the app urls directory:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('users.urls')),
]
```

Here is the urls file in the users application:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

------------------ UPDATE -----------------------------

this is the views.py file in the users app:

from django.shortcuts import render

```
from general.models import Profile, Request, Friend, UserActivity, Privacy
from general.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm, ProfileForm, VerifyPersonalForm
from general.forms import VerifyBusinessForm, AccountUpdateForm, UserUpdateForm
from general.forms import InfoUpdateForm, PasswordUpdateForm, PrivacyUpdateForm

# the users login  view
def user_login(request):
    # check if the form was submitted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # grab the form
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        # validation of the form
        if form.is_valid():
            # cleaned up data from form
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username = cd['username']
            password = cd['password']
            # authenticate with the user record
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # check if login credentials are authentic
            if user:
                # login the user to django session
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('groups')
            else:
                # re-display form with error message
                # the same form
                form = LoginForm()
                # the error
                error = 'Invalid Username/Password'
                # template parameters to display
                parameters = {
                    'form':form,
                    'error':error
                }
                # re-render the template
                return render(request, 'users/login.html', parameters)
    else:
        # display the form for submission
        form = LoginForm()
        # the template parameters
        parameters = {
            'form':form,
        }
        # render the login template
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', parameters)
```

Here is the forms.py file in the general app:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from localflavor.us.forms import USStateField, USPhoneNumberField, USZipCodeField

from .models import *

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        help_text="")
    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text='')
    verify = forms.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'verify', 'email']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender_choices = (('M', 'Male'),
                      ('F', 'Female'),
                      ('O', 'Other'))
    # uncomment for both personal and business accounts
    # account_choices = (('INDIVIDUAL', 'Individual'),
    #                    ('BUSINESS', 'Business'))
    f_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    l_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    bio = forms.CharField(label='Bio')
    dob = forms.DateField(
        label='Date of Birth',
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
    )
    gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices = gender_choices,
        label='Gender'
    )
    # uncomment for personal and business accounts
    # account = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    #     choices = account_choices
    # )
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['f_name', 'l_name', 'bio', 'dob', 'gender', 'phone']

class VerifyPersonalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dba = forms.CharField(label='Company')
    lob = forms.CharField(label='Occupation')
    street = forms.CharField(label='Street')
    city = forms.CharField(label='City')
    ssn = forms.IntegerField(label='SSN - Last 4')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['dba', 'lob', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']

class VerifyBusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dba = forms.CharField(label='Company')
    lob = forms.CharField(label='Industry')
    street = forms.CharField(label='Street')
    city = forms.CharField(label='City')
    tin = forms.IntegerField(label='TIN/EIN')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['dba', 'lob', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']

# the form for updating users accounts
class AccountUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

# the form allows the user to update public information
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="First Name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="Last Name")
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['bio', 'first_name', 'last_name']

# the following will allow user to update his profile infomraiton
class InfoUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['phone', 'dob', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']

# the form that will update the users Password
class PasswordUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    current_password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="Current password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    new_password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="New password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    verify_password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="Verify password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

# the form is going to be used to update the users privacy settings
class PrivacyUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    privacy_choices = (('1', 'Everyone'),
                       ('2', 'Friends'),
                       ('3', 'Only Me'))
    friends = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label="Friends", choices=privacy_choices
    )
    groups = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label="Friends", choices=privacy_choices
    )
    expenses = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label="Friends", choices=privacy_choices
    )
    searchable = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label="Friends", choices=privacy_choices
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Privacy
        fields = ['friends', 'groups', 'expenses', 'searchable']
```

If someone help me figure out why I am getting this error or what it means so that I can figure out how to fix it, I would really appreciate it a lot. I also have another applicaiton in the project called General that has all of the models and forms stored in it and the app imports the required models and forms for usage.

Comment: can you post the forms file full and also the views file full

Comment: will update the post with full files @Exprator

Comment: all the forms are stored in the general app and the views are in the users app

Comment: that i understood from the error, but i need to see it, maybe the error lies there

Comment: if you need a line number, I can tell you what line it is ...

Comment: uninstall localflavor, thats where the conflict is, check once by removing localflavor from installed apps wherever you have used

Comment: that was it, It is working.. thank you so much for that